# C# HttpWebResponse GetResponse throwing 404 Error because it needs to be redirected

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-status-code-404, webrequest

I am currently designing an application that reads ID's from a text file and then adds it to the URL address... so urlhere is actually www.website.com/ID.  The only problem is that the website redirects from www.website.com/ID to www.website.com/username.  Is there a way I can tell the application to wait for the redirecting to happen?  I want to get information from the source of www.website.com/username.  Unfortunately I cannot because my application is currently trying to GetResponse() from the www.website.com/ID and throwing the exception error for 404 not found.  Unfortunately I cannot get the username so I cannot do www.website.com/username. Any suggestions will help.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
                WebRequest.Create(urlhere);
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/16.02 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            // execute the request

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
                    request.GetResponse();
```